# How can I make a loop that calls dataframes

Tags: r, list, loops, dataframe

I have the wrote the code below for a transformation of rows of a dataframe to colums

```
RowsToColums <- function(df)
{
  model = list()
  
  for(i in seq_along(df))
  {
    if(i>4)
    {
      dataf <- data.frame(names = df[1], Year=colnames(df[i]),  index = df[,i:i])
      names(dataf)[3]<- toString(df[[3]][2])
      names(dataf)[1]<- "Country"
      model[[i]] <- dataf
    }
    
  }
  df <- do.call(rbind, model)
  df <- arrange(df, Country)
}


EC_Pop            <- RowsToColums(EC_Pop)
EC_GDP            <- RowsToColums(EC_GDP)
EC_Inflation      <- RowsToColums(EC_Inflation)
ST_Tech_Exp       <- RowsToColums(ST_Tech_Exp)
ST_Res_Jour       <- RowsToColums(ST_Res_Jour)
ST_Res_Exp        <- RowsToColums(ST_Res_Exp)
ST_Res_Pop        <- RowsToColums(ST_Res_Pop)
ED_Unempl         <- RowsToColums(ED_Unempl)
ED_Edu_Exp        <- RowsToColums(ED_Edu_Exp)
```

But as you can see, I call many times the same function.

I tried to move all these dataframes in a vector like this

```
list_a = list(EC_Pop,EC_GDP,EC_Inflation,ST_Tech_Exp,ST_Res_Exp)
for (i in seq_along(list_a))
{
  list_a[i] <- RowsToColums(list_a[i]) 
}
```

write a loop that everytime take the dataframe but it fails with an error

```
UseMethod ("arrange_") error:
   Inapplicable method for 'arrange_' applied to object of class "NULL"
```

Does anybody know how to fix this case?

Comment: Take a look at the `get` function and use the calling environment of the function

Comment: you can apply functions to list of objects with `lapply(list_a, RowsToColums)`

Comment: Given the error, it seems like something fails in this line `df <- arrange(df, Country)`. I'd say that df ends up being NULL in one (or more) of the cases. Otherwise, as suggested above there are base R options to apply a function to all members of a list as well as `purrr` options.

Comment: Also, in order to "get" to the data frames in the for loop use double bracket indexation: `list_a[[i]] <- RowsToColums(list_a[[i]])`

Comment: Valeri Voev  this doesn't work. It was also one of my experiments. Also, my function works fine because when I call it outside of the loop the result is exactly what I want.

Daniel O, this works but as with map function that I used before I cannot return the dataframe to list again because I have an error when I use 

df <- do.call(rbind, model)

that says :Error in match.names (clabs, names (xi)):
   Names do not match the previous names

I understand that the names is the problem but I cannon see anything weird...